# How to download YouTube videos using browser?

Tags: 8.1, apps, lumia-520, video

I am using a Nokia Lumia 520 (Lumia Cyan) with Windows Phone 8.1. I came to know YouTube downloader and its defect of letting the videos to SD card. Once I tried downloading YouTube videos using [Clip Convertor](http://www.clipconverter.cc) and it worked for some time in UC Browser. Later it was not working. Then I tried copying the YouTube video link and pasted it in http://www.keepvid.com (it's an open-source video downloader). It worked for some time and now it's not working. It shows the error as there is no Java enabled on your browser. I checked all the setting in UC browser and enabled everything and still it's failing. I tried this on Internet Explorer too. But everything seems to fail. Can someone suggest me how to download YouTube videos through the browser or through any apps that can transfer the videos to SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple - download UC Browser and go to Youtube. Once you click on a video it will be opened in a window. You will have a small blue-colored video button at the bottom left corner of the browser. Once you click it, it will ask for download. Then you can download the video. The only disadvantage is that you can't select the desired resolution with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [myTube!](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/mytube/d994dce8-38f9-4ed3-ae6c-e334d4bd558c). It's feature rich YouTube client with the ability to download videos. The videos will be downloaded in the same quality that you set the reproduction quality. So, you can choose the quality that you want to download the videos.